# Docx4j with grails. Convert HTML to word document

Tags: java, grails, docx4j

I'm using Docx4j 3.1.0 with Xalan 2.7.1 in grails 2.3.7. Here I've done the integration of docx4j with grails and I'm able to generate word document. But I want pass a gsp or html template to the Docx4j and generate word document. Is it possible ? And if yes, how to do it? As well as how to pass image which can be displayed in document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [docx4j-ImportXHTML](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML); see the [examples](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML/tree/master/src/samples/java/org/docx4j/samples).