# convert AngularJS to word document

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc, docx4j

I have in my disposal a Spring MVC backed server, using AngularJS in client side to display dynamic content. Was researching possibility to get current content displayed in the browser and convert it to a word document.
I assume there's a way to do build word documents with Java, but to do so i'll have to send existing HTML to the server side - how would i do that? just send the document DOM object?
Suppose i'll be able to do so, what if i want to include 2 images? I do know its possible to send images as base64 string.
To conclude, my general approach would be to try and send all client side data to the server and use Java to generate word document.
I have found [docx4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23467369/docx4j-with-grails-convert-html-to-word-document) so this approach seems possible.

Is that the right way to go? Any thoughts would be appriciated.

Comment: Maybe of interest http://www.docx4java.org/blog/2014/10/web-based-docx-editing/

Comment: Thank you @JasonPlutext, but it didn't work for me- will try again after Apache POI attempt.

Comment: Meanwhile, i'd appreciate some input regarding the downvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the server side, you can use a library like [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) for creating docx documents.

There are multiple ways to pass data from client to server:

- Make an AJAX call

  - [How to send FormData objects with Ajax-requests in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974684/)
  - [Ajax Upload image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19447435/)
- Submit a form from the client side to the server using POST. Using multi-part forms  will allow you to send attachments to the server

  - See [Handling HTML (multipart form-data) file uploads with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833108)

On the client side, there are some JS libraries available for creating docx documents:

- https://github.com/evidenceprime/html-docx-js
- [Generate a Word document in JavaScript with Docx.js ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15899883/)

Comment: Am trying the Apache POI app, will update for results